# Wordpress - Null error on Mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, null

I have http://geoffjorgensen.com working fine on the desktop but I can't access it on either Safari or Chrome on my phone. Help!? Thanks!

Comment: Just tried chrome on phone.  No issues.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't give the server enough time to propogate, everything's fine, whoops!